# Inner select query in linq query c#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check values that are present in other table, not from fixed list or array. here is an example of what I need. Actually I am querying EF.

```
Database_EF db = new Database_EF();

var listA = (from a in db.a
            where a.id in 
                (from b in db.b 
                 join c in db.c on b.id equals c.id
                 where c.col1 equals 'something'
                 select b.id)
             select a.id).ToList();
```

I am new to linq. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using `Contains`, like `where (from b in db.b ...).Contains(a.id)`?  Basically `x in y` in SQL is the equivalent of `y.Contains(x)` in Linq.

Comment: Is the data in a DataTable or are you querying the database?

Comment: I am querying Entity Framework. Please see the edit.

Comment: Also it gives me error at `where a.id..` that, `cannot implicitly convert System.Guid to bool`. Second error at `a.id in` that `invalid expression in` and third in inner query at `equals 'something')` that `; expected`.

Comment: SQL `x IN (subquery)` is mapped to LINQ `(subquery).Contains(x)`. Also LINQ requires `select` statement. e.g. `where (from b .... select b.id).Contains(a.id)`

Comment: Apology for the `select statement`. I have edited my question.

Comment: `equals` is only used for joins.  In a `where` cause you should use `==` like `where c.col1 == "something"`.  (notice you need double quotes for a string also)

Answer (score 3):

Should be something like this:

```
var listA = (from a in db.a
             where (from b in db.b
                    join c in db.c on b.id equals c.id
                    where c.col1 == "something"
                    select b.id).Contains(a.id)
             select a.id).ToList();
```